# What is hostPropertyName of @HostBinding(hostPropertyName)

Tags: angular

@HostBinding() decorator take in argument an 'hostPropertyName'.

Do you know what is this host ? And how can we find his available property ?

Answer (score 3):

So far I only found that you can bind to HTML attributes and classes of that component.

```
attr.myAttr

class.myClass
```

At the moment of writing this answer, the NG2 doc itself is lacking of important information such as what you are looking for. I hope they will improve it soon.